# inner join returns wrong value for 1 of the fields

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am using the following query to extract info from a mysql database and although I get the correct value for min( qt.quote_price ), I get the wrong value for st.Supplier_id.

It seems to return the first st.Supplier_id from the table which meets the where clause but obviously I want it to return the st.Supplier_id of the row with the min( qt.quote_price ).

I am sure this is simple but for some reason I just can't figure it out and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

```
SELECT ft.fuel_type_id, ft.fuel_name, st.Supplier_id, st.company_name as company_name, st.email, qt.supplier_id, qt.timestamp, qt.fuel_type_id, min( qt.quote_price ) AS best_derv
FROM tbl_quote qt
INNER JOIN `tbl_suppliers` st ON qt.supplier_id = st.Supplier_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_fuel-type` ft ON qt.fuel_type_id = ft.fuel_type_id
WHERE qt.fuel_type_id =3 AND qt.timestamp > date_sub( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )
```

I have edited the query to something which works but I would appreciate any help to improve it (if possible).

```
SELECT qt.quote_id, ft.fuel_type_id, ft.fuel_name, st.Supplier_id, st.company_name as company_name, st.email, qt.supplier_id, qt.timestamp, qt.fuel_type_id, min( qt.quote_price ) AS best_derv
FROM tbl_quote qt
INNER JOIN `tbl_suppliers` st ON qt.supplier_id = st.Supplier_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_fuel-type` ft ON qt.fuel_type_id = ft.fuel_type_id
WHERE qt.quote_price = (Select min(quote_price) from tbl_quote where fuel_type_id =3 AND timestamp > date_sub( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY ))
```

Comment: Please create sql fiddle and minimize the query to the minimal example, still reproducing the error. Remove all the unnecessary fields and unrelated tables. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: it told me that I am returning all rows in the tbl_quote table which is my problem, I'll get back to working on it tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `GROUP BY` clause that lists all non-aggregate columns:

```
SELECT ft.fuel_type_id, ft.fuel_name, st.Supplier_id, st.company_name as company_name, st.email, qt.supplier_id, qt.timestamp, qt.fuel_type_id, min( qt.quote_price ) AS best_derv
FROM tbl_quote qt
INNER JOIN `tbl_suppliers` st ON qt.supplier_id = st.Supplier_id
INNER JOIN `tbl_fuel-type` ft ON qt.fuel_type_id = ft.fuel_type_id
WHERE qt.fuel_type_id =3
AND qt.timestamp > date_sub( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )
GROUP BY ft.fuel_type_id, ft.fuel_name, st.Supplier_id, st.company_name, st.email, qt.supplier_id, qt.timestamp, qt.fuel_type_id
```

In all other (non-mysql) databases you would have received an error message that described the problem, but mysql allows this situation, in which case it returns the first row instead of the aggregated rows.

Comment: I changed st.company_name as company_name, to either st.company_name or company_name and it returned the 3 rows which meet the where criteria, I need to figure our how to just show the row I want, thanks.

Comment: Oops, I just copy-pasted (I fixed the answer). Now, what do you mean by "the right row"? Tell me more and I can help you

Comment: I just want to return the row which includes the min(qt.quote_price) so that I can use the company_name and other fields from this row later on the webpage to create automatic emails and also update other tables in the database